# How to get text between two specific strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to get the text and the specific string ,till it matches another one. I have 
"Door number: 5
Behind this door bla bla bla...

Door number: 6
Behind this door bla bla bla"
I need to get "Door number: 5
Behind this door bla bla bla..."

```
String str = " Door 51 text1 Door 61 text2 Door 10 text3";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\bPage\\b\\s\\d+(.*?)\\s\\bPage\\b\\s\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

This is my code , but i get only text1 when I run it.I need Door 51 text1, Door 61 text2, Door 10 text3.

Comment: Why not just split the string on ` Door` , then split the resulting strings after the first space? Convert the first part to int. This way, you'll end up with something like `[[61, "text2"], [10, "text3"]]`. No need for regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead instead of the consuming pattern after `(.*?)` as the matches turn out overlapping:

```
\bDoor\s+\d+(.*?)(?=\bDoor\s+\d+|$)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vbmPku/1).

The `(?=\bDoor\s+\d+|$)` lookahead will require the end of string `$` or `Door` (as a whole word), 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) and 1+ digits (`\d+`) after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*?`). Note that a word boundary in `r\b\s` makes no sense, since `\s` does not match a word char, so I adjusted the pattern a bit.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/dGSXU1):

```
 String str = " Door 51 text1 Door 61 text2 Door 10 text3";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bDoor\\s+\\d+(.*?)(?=\\bDoor\\s+\\d+|$)");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
 while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
 }
```

An [alternative solution](https://ideone.com/aj5PJ4) with `split`:

```
String str = "Door 51 text1 Door 61 text2 Door 10 text3";
String[] doors = str.replaceFirst("^\\s*\\bDoor\\s+\\d+\\s*", "").split("\\s*\\bDoor\\s+\\d+\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doors));
// = > [text1, text2, text3]
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution worked, i just used group() instead of group(1).

Comment: So, you need to keep `Doors...`? Then you can use the second approach with a lookahead - `String[] doors = str.split("(?=\\bDoor\\s+\\d+)");`. See [**this IDEONE demo**](https://ideone.com/R0Npvk).